# How to find the radius of convergence of $\sum_{n=k}^{\infty}k^n\left(\frac{z}{2}\right)^n$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, derivatives

My teacher wrote this

$$
\frac{1}{R}=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\left|{\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}}\right|
$$
$$
\frac{1}{R}=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\left|{\frac{k^{n+1}}{2^n2}.\frac{2^n}{k^{n}}}\right|
$$
$$
\frac{1}{R}=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\left|{\frac{1}{2}.\frac{(n+1)!}{k!(n+1-k)!}.\frac{k!(n-k)!}{n!}}\right|
$$

My question is where did the last line come from?

Comment: ...I agree...what is that last line?

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt, Does it have to do with the fact that the sum starts from $k$ not $1$?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is completely trivial.

Comment: The radius of convergence is clearly $2/k$ since $\sum_{n\geq N_0}\left(\frac{k z}{2}\right)^n$ is a geometric series.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio, but my teacher showed that the radius equals $2$.

Comment: @MrDi, the last line came from a different problem.

Comment: Is the $k^n$ in fact $\binom{k}{n}$ ?

Comment: @Kelenner, I think this may be it.

Comment: I think the OP *must* address the question: what in the world **for his problem** do line 2 , 3 have in common ?? (Hint: the answer is *nothing*. The question thus is: why did he write it there?)